# Interface between service and regular typescript class?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a unique situation and I find myself quite stuck. I have a standard typescript class (`.ts`) extension, that needs to use methods from an angular2 service. So far I can't see a way to achieve this.

I'm going to try an explain this as simply as I possibly can, as my code base is currently quite complex.

The service in question is `operation.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Operation } from './operation';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class OperationService {

  private operationCatalogue: Operation[] = [];
  private url = './src/app/operation-catalogue/operations.json';

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.init();
  }

  init(){
      this.fetchOperations().subscribe(res => {
        var i;
        for(i in res["operations"]){
          this.operationCatalogue[i] = new Operation(res["operations"][i]["name"],
                                                     res["operations"][i]["description"],
                                                     res["operations"][i]["iconName"],
                                                     res["operations"][i]["inputs"],
                                                     res["operations"][i]["outputs"]
                                                 );
        }
      });
  }

  getOperations(){
    return this.operationCatalogue;
  }

  fetchOperations(): Observable<Operation[]>{
      return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
  }

  /*
  Get a single operation from the operation catalogue.
  */
  getOperation(name: String): Operation {
    var theOne;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.operationCatalogue.length; i++){
        if (this.operationCatalogue[i].name === name){
            theOne = this.operationCatalogue[i];
        }
    }
    return theOne;
  }
}
```

You'll see from this code that the service builds an of these `Operation` objects from data found in a locally sourced `.json` file. In production, my application will get the data from a server rather than a local file.

The important method to note is `getOperation()` which takes a string and returns an `Operation` object from the array.

This service is a key part of my application, and is used to populate a HTML list in another component.

Now, I have another class, called `WSJSerializer`. Put simply, and just to give you some context, this class takes a JSON string which represents an array of Operation objects that were found on disk and turns them into `Operation` objects. **In order to do this, `WSJSerializer` needs to use the `getOperation()` method of `OperationService`.**

`WSJSerializer.ts`:

```
export class WSJDeserializer {

    private jsonString : string;
    private parsedString : Object;

    constructor(string : String){
        this.jsonString = <string> string;
        this.parsedString = JSON.parse(this.jsonString);
    }

    public deserialize() {
        var rootOp = this.parsedString["operation"];
        var childOps = rootOp["operations"];
        var numOps = childOps.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < numOps; i++){
            var childOp = childOps[i]["operation"];
            this.deserializeObject(childOp);
        }
    }

    private deserializeObject(operation : Object){
        //NEED TO USE THE getOperation() METHOD HERE!!!!
    }
}
```

This is the crux of my problem. I'm unable to interface with `OperationService` from `WSJSerializer`, I'm guessing it's some sort of angular restriction. I tried to `import` `OperationService` into `WSJSerializer` and then call the `getOperation()` method, but I got the following error:

```
WSJDeserializer.ts (25,26): Property 'getOperations' does not exist on type 'typeof OperationService'.)
```

**How can I call the `getOperation()` method of `OperationService` from within `WSJSerializer`?** **If it's not directly possible, can I write some sort of interface (not an OO-concept interface) or helper class to solve the problem? Is there some other workaround?**

Other information:

- `WSJSerializer` is used in the root angular component of my application but `OperationService` is not.
- `OperationService` is used in a child component of the root component, of which the root component has direct access to via a `ViewChild()`.
- `WSJSerializer` is not a service because it needs to directly modify other angular components by calling their methods.

Root component where `WSJSerializer` is used:

```
import { WSJDeserializer } from './serialization/WSJDeserializer';

//services...
import { SerializationService } from './serialization/serialization.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [SerializationService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(PixiComponent) private pixiComponent : PixiComponent;
    @ViewChild(LogComponent) private logComponent : LogComponent;
    @ViewChild(EditGlobalNamesDialogBoxComponent) private globalNamesEditDialog : EditGlobalNamesDialogBoxComponent;
    @ViewChild(GlobalNamesComponent) private globalNamesComponent : GlobalNamesComponent;

    private globalNamesController : GlobalNamesController;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.globalNamesController = new GlobalNamesController(this.globalNamesEditDialog, this.globalNamesComponent, this.pixiComponent);
    }

    public leftMousedown(){
        this.pixiComponent.clickFromOutside();
    }

    public rightMousedown($event){
        $event.preventDefault();
        this.pixiComponent.clickFromOutside();
    }

    //TODO: Escape key functionality
    notifyEscapePressed(){

    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Following method for log functionality

    public logData($event){
        this.logComponent.logText($event);
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Following methods for global names functionality 
    // handled by this.globalNamesController

    public globalNameEditRequest(data : EditGlobalNameRequestData){
        this.globalNamesController.displayEditGlobalNamesDialogBox(data);
    }

    public setNewGlobalName(data : EditGlobalNameRequestData) {
        this.globalNamesController.setNewGlobalName(data);
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Deserialization...

    public deserialize($event){
        var workspaceString : String = $event;
        var deserializer : WSJDeserializer = new WSJDeserializer(workspaceString)
        this.pixiComponent.resetCanvas();
        deserializer.deserialize();
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `OperationService` as a dependency in your `WSJSerializer` constructor?

Comment: @Saravana I tried injecting `OperationService` into `WSJSerializer` like this: `constructor(@Inject(OperationService) private operationService)`, but when I try to instantiate `WSJSerializer`, it gives me an error because it expects an `OperationService` object to be passed in, even though it's being injected...

Comment: The question misses the obvious important part - how WSJSerializer is used and why it's not a service.

Comment: @estus The reason `WSJSerializer` is not a service is because it needs to directly modify other angular components - which is not what services should be used for. I will edit my question to add this information.

Comment: Services are to make use of Angular DI, no more, no less. Please, provide the code for the components where WSJSerializer is used.

Comment: @estus I have added the code where `WSJSerializer` is used, it is used in the `deserialize()` method of the root component

Comment: You should not be writing code like this. Most of your type annotations are wrong. Your deserialized method makes no sense to me. How does it not return a value. Seems useless. Also, why do you even have instance state in the serializer?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you for the feedback. Could you please point out which type annotations are wrong? The deserialize method doesn't need to return anything, it performs an action which makes sense in the context of my application, the details of which I have left out because they aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: @JavascriptLoser all uses of `String` and `Object`: never use the initial cap versions of intrinsic types, use `string` or `object` or `{}`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you for this advice. May I ask the reason?

Comment: @JavascriptLoser you can read about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html Basically they are not the types that you might think they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current state `WSJSerializer` has to make use of DI pattern (not Angular DI) in order to get an instance of `OperationService`:

```
export class WSJDeserializer {
    ...
    constructor(private operationService: OperationService, string : String){
        this.jsonString = <string> string;
        this.parsedString = JSON.parse(this.jsonString);
    }
    ...
    private deserializeObject(operation : Object){
        this.operationService.getOperation(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Which should be passed from an injectable that instantiates this class, i.e. a component:

```
new WSJDeserializer(workspaceString, this.operationService)
```

This looks like a design issue and the proper refactoring solution may depend on the other factors that weren't explained in the question.

One possibility is that wrong things was taken as entities for the class. Is there a real need for an object that holds state (`parsedString`) and is able to deserialize it more than once? If there isn't then serializer can become singleton injectable that accepts a string as an argument for its methods:

```
@Injectable()
export class WSJDeserializer {
    constructor(private operationService: OperationService) {}

    deserialize(string : String) {
            ...
            this.deserializeObject(string , childOp);
            ...
    }

    private deserializeObject(string : String, operation : Object){
        this.operationService.getOperation(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Another possibility is that the entities are right, but there's a real need to have an instance that holds state, so one class is not enough. Singleton injectable should exist any way in order to get `OperationService`. So there should be two classes instead of one:

```
export class WSJDeserializable {
    ...
    constructor(string : String){
        this.jsonString = <string> string;
        this.parsedString = JSON.parse(this.jsonString);
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class WSJDeserializer {
    constructor(private operationService: OperationService) {}

    deserialize(deserializableObj: WSJDeserializable) {
            ...
            this.deserializeObject(deserializableObj, childOp);
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Which should be passed from a component:

```
const deserializableObj = new WSJDeserializable(...);
deserializer.deserialize(deserializableObj);
```

There are more options to do this, e.g. `WSJDeserializer` instance can have factory method that creates `WSJDeserializable` instances, but in the end it stays a singleton, because Angular services are singletons (within a single injector).

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. Your suggestion to not save state of the string is indeed what the solution called for.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess this is a common design problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need an instance of `OperationService` inside of `WSJSerializer`? There is only *one* way to do that and that is through the injector. In order to make `WSJSerializer` injectable, you must turn it into a service.

Well, that is a little bit of a lie. There is another way. If you can't make `WSJSerializer` a service, then you will also need to ensure that `OperationService` is also not a service. This is fairly easy to do.  Instead of using the angular `Http` service, you can use native libraries instead (either [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (note that fetch only works on modern browsers).

Comment: Assuming I decide to turn `WSJSerializer` into a service, how can I get an instance of `OperationService` into it?

Comment: You add `@Injectable()` to the class declaration and in the class constructor, add a parameter of type `OperationService`. Then add the `WSJSerializer` as a provider in your component.